# Filtering a query using include/exclude pools

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a very simple tagging system working for a video collection of mine, with which I'm using SQLite. I am working on implementing one feature that has me stumped. I would like to be able to retrieve videos with an 'include/exclude' pool. IE:

- Get all videos that are tagged *'nature'*, *'grass'*, *'sky'*
- Exclude all videos that are tagged *'horror'*, *'gore'*, etc.

My structure is the following:

[image: image of basic table structure]

And I'm currently able to pull all videos with a tag using the following query:

```
SELECT Media.filename FROM Tags 
INNER JOIN Media_Tags ON Tags.id = Media_Tags.tag_id 
INNER JOIN Media ON Media_Tags.media_id = Media.id 
WHERE Tags.name = 'people'
```

What I have tried to do is perform is:

```
SELECT Media.filename FROM Tags 
INNER JOIN Media_Tags ON Tags.id = Media_Tags.tag_id 
INNER JOIN Media ON Media_Tags.media_id = Media.id 
WHERE Tags.name = 'people' 
AND Tags.name = 'seinfeld' 
AND Tags.name != 'elaine'
AND Tags.name != 'george'
```

The problem becomes obvious when I see that I'm retrieving all videos for a tag, instead of all tags for a video, so this is always returning zero records. It's at this point that I am unsure on rewriting this query.

Could anyone provide me some guidance on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation and `having`:

```
SELECT m.filename
FROM Tags t INNER JOIN
     Media_Tags mt
     ON t.id = mt.tag_id INNER JOIN
     Media m
     ON mt.media_id = m.id 
GROUP BY m.filename
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t.name = 'people' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.name = 'seinfeld' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.name = 'elaine' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.name = 'george' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 ;
```

Each condition in the `HAVING` clause tests one condition for each tag on each `filename`.  The `> 0` says that the tag is present; `= 0` says that the tag is not present.

Your original question is answered the same way:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t.name = 'nature' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.name = 'grass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.name = 'sky' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.name = 'horror' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.name = 'gore' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 ;
```